# UWP "Type" Dependency Property

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I was trying to create a behavior in UWP, would like to have a dependency property "Type TargetType", as the code shows below. Intention was use Type so that XAML editor could recognize it and auto complete/import the namespace of the type like Style.TargetType does.

But once I run the program I got crash.

Using StringToTypeConverter lost autocomplete capability in xaml editor.

So How can I do this like Style?

Dependency property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetType), typeof(Type), typeof(LazyIWorkVmBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public Type TargetType
{
    get { return (Type) GetValue(TargetTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value);}
}
```

Usage:

```
<mvvmLazyControl:LazyIWorkVmBehavior TargetType="viewModel:WorkVm2" />
```

Error msg:
WinRT information: Failed to create a 'MvvmLazyControl.LazyIWorkVmBehavior' from the text 'viewModel:WorkVm2'. [Line: 42 Position: 46]

Project: https://github.com/sharethl/UWPTargetTypeDependencyTest

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know how you defined the `Type` object `viewModel:WorkVm2`, I just tried your dependency property successfully on my side by code as follows:

```
<local:LazyIWorkVmBehavior TargetType="local:Withinstyle" />
<local:LazyIWorkVmBehavior TargetType="Button" />
<local:LazyIWorkVmBehavior TargetType="local:Secondpage" />
```

`Withinstyle` is a custom control in my project,`Secondpage` is a `xaml` page in my project. Both of them can run successfully in my project. I can reproduce your exception by set a `TargetType` object with a wrong prefix or without a prefix. So please confirm you have included an xmlns prefix `viewModel` for the custom type `WorkVm2` and make sure the `WorkVm2` exists in the `viewModel` namespace.

Another thing, according to the [Style.TargetType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.style.targettype.aspx) article:

> The typical way to specify a TargetType value is through a XAML attribute on the Style element. When set in XAML, the meaning of TargetType and the values you provide take on some aspects of how types are represented in XAML.

Although this is for `Style` element, but for your custom `LazyIWorkVmBehavior`, in my opinion, the custom `TargetType` should also can be represented in XAML.

Comment: I tried UserControl and Page in TargetType, both are working.
But for pure class like public class WorkVm{}, or Vm derived from ViewModelBase from mvvmlight will crash. Namespace are correct.

Comment: I have moved all my pure classes(only .cs file) to same level as Page.xaml file. So namespace should be a problem.

    <local:LazyIWorkVmBehavior TargetType="local:WorkVm1" />

Comment: @ Sunteen - MSFT The crash problem is not solved yet. It is not related to namespace issue. As my previous comment said, even I moved WorkVm1 to top level folder (namespace) it still crashes.

Comment: @TonghuaLi. can the `WorkVm1` be represented in XAML? As I said in my reply, according to the `style.TargetType` article, the custom TargetType should also can be represented in XAML since you use it in XAML.

Comment: Could you point me what is it mean represented in XAML?  this is my WorkVm1 class, 'public class WorkVm1{}'. Interesting thing is that "MyUserControl1.xaml" works while "DerivedUserControl.cs" not works. I have uploaded the test project here, please take a look. https://github.com/sharethl/UWPTargetTypeDependencyTest